# How to remove null attributes with table row from popup using Arcade expression in ArcGIS Portal

Tags: expression, popup, arcgis-portal, arcade, configuration

I am using the HTML code to configure the popup

```
<font size="2">
<table border="1">

<tbody>
<tr>
<td><b><font color="#000000">Land Class :</font></b></td>
<td><b><font color="#000000">{land_class}</font></b></td>
</tr>

<tr style="display:{expression/expr1}">
<td><b><font color="#000000">Name of Allottee :</font></b></td>
<td><b><font color="#000000">{name_alote}<br /></font></b></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table></font>
```

using expression

```
IIF(isEmpty($feature.name_alote), "none", "inline")
```

and the output is shown like this

[image]

But I want, if the value is null then the complete table row needs to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

The following approach worked in ArcGIS Pro so should translate to ArcGIS Online.

In the configure pop-up add your fields, including the ones that may have null values which become the table rows you wish to exclude.  Then convert it all into HTML by turning on the HTML mode.

[image: HTML mode]

Now for the row that might have no data and you want to drop, copy all the code between html tags `<tr></tr>`.

Return to the main pop-up configure section and click on Expressions and create a new expression, lets call it `killrow`. In its expression type in:

```
iif(isempty($feature.XYZ),"","<tr valign='top' style='background-color: rgb(224, 224, 224);'>.....</tr>")
```

Where XYZ is the field name. You'll need to remove any newline characters that you would have copied over from the HTML text bit. You are saying if the field is empty return an empty string, if it has a value return the HTML that creates a row and formats it.

Now back in the section that is the HTML replace every between `<tr></tr>` with `{expression/killrow}`

A simple example of a completed HTML table that calls killrow on a single row is below:

```html
<table style='vertical-align: top;width: 100%;background-color: #F7F7F7;border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;font-family: Segoe UI, Tahoma, Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 9pt;'>
  <tbody>
    <tr valign='top' style='background-color: rgb(224, 224, 224);'>
      <td style='padding: 2px;padding-bottom: 5px;border: 1px solid rgb(203, 203, 203);padding-right: 5px;color:rgb(74, 74, 74);'>toid</td>
      <td style='padding: 2px;padding-bottom: 5px;border: 1px solid rgb(203, 203, 203);color:rgb(0, 0, 0);'>{toid}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign='top' style='background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);'>
      <td style='padding: 2px;padding-bottom: 5px;border: 1px solid rgb(203, 203, 203);padding-right: 5px;color:rgb(74, 74, 74);'>wb_cat</td>
      <td style='padding: 2px;padding-bottom: 5px;border: 1px solid rgb(203, 203, 203);color:rgb(0, 0, 0);'>{wb_cat}</td>
    </tr>
    {expression/killrow}
  </tbody>
</table>
```